# how to get all plugins mentioned in bootstrap webpage?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am reading javascript tab
(http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
I found something like  transition.js,modal.js. Where can I get them?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is a bad question. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: The link clearly states `If you're using the compiled (or minified) bootstrap.js, there is no need to include this—it's already there.`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the documentation.

Comment: _Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual *.js files), or all at once (using bootstrap.js or the minified bootstrap.min.js)._

Answer (score 1):

From the top of that page:

> Using the compiled JavaScript
>   Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file.